# unknown intent-filter error in android studio Error:(104) error: unknown element <intent-filter> found

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

I received an android application code from a friend. When I open this project in my Android Studio v3.0.1, and build the project, Gradle gives error for AndroidManifest.xml on using intent-filter

Here are the wording of the error

```
Error:(104) error: unknown element <intent-filter> found.
```

Please help to resolve this issue

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because the AndroidManifest.xml file does not conform to the Android Manifest element hierarchy. AAPT/AAPT2 is informing you through the error message:

```
Error:(104) error: unknown element <intent-filter> found.
```

Open your AndroidManifest.xml file and search for the `intent-filter` tag. One one them will be misplaced under a node it does not belong to.

For more information about Android Manifest element hierarchy look at the [official Android Developers Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element).

Answer (score 1):

You might have a misplaced tag. The new AAPT (AAPT2) now throws an error on this.
Share your code!